# How to pass parameters from Data Factory to Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I try to pass 2 parameters from Data Factory to Azure Functions. Everything works well if I hardcode the parameter values in Body as follows:

```
{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}
```

However, if I try to use `@pipeline().parameters.param1` and `@pipeline().parameters.param2`, then it fails because the values are None. The pipeline parameters `param1` and `param2` are defined correctly and they are passed correctly to, e.g., Databricks.

```
{"param1":@pipeline().parameters.param1,"param2":@pipeline().parameters.param2}
```

As the header I pass: `Content-Type` equal to `application/json`.

What is wrong in my expression?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this expression:

```
@concat('{"param1":"', pipeline().parameters.param1, '", "param2":"', pipeline().parameters.param2,'"}')
```

Comment: Came across the same problem and confirm this way of assembling the JSON with pipeline parameters works.